# Trouble with scroll event

Tags: javascript, events, frontend

I wanted to make a script that makes `div` with id `header` thinner while scrolling, and thicker when you go back to the top of the page. But I got a problem: when I scroll down, `header` becomes thinner, but when I go back to the top of the page, it doesn't become thicker, and also if you reload web-page being somewhere in the middle and then you go to the top, `header` becomes thicker only once.

What did I do wrong?

```js
var head = document.getElementById('header');
var height = 100;
var sourceCoord = head.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
var id;

document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sourceCoord) {
    id = setInterval(function() {
      if (height == 50) clearInterval(id);
      else {
        height--;
        head.style.height = height + "px";
      }
    }, 10);
    head.style.position = 'fixed';
  } else if (window.pageYOffset <= sourceCoord) {
    id = setInterval(function() {
      if (height == 100) clearInterval(id);
      else {
        height++;
        head.style.height = height + "px";
      }
    }, 10);
    head.style.position = "absolute";
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you calculate the `sourceCoord` upon page load, while it actually changes upon scroll. Include it in the scroll listener and you should be good.